# Comparing two SMPS in terms of DC output to earth isolation

Tags: power-supply

Regarding the following supplies:

https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/HDR-60/HDR-60-spec.pdf

and

https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/ELP-75/ELP-75-spec.pdf

Their block diagrams are give as:

[image]

and

[image]

What could be the reason there's a capacitor between negative DC output and the frame ground? I was wondering if there's any advantage one over the other. I want to make dual supply using two single output supplies in series operation; and was wondering if one of them result more noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What could be the reason there's a capacitor between negative DC
> output and the frame ground?*

Highly likely that the capacitor is there to reduce output emissions. The emissions are due to the transformer capacitively coupling switching artefacts in the primary (via inter-winding capacitance) to the secondary. The added capacitor will significantly reduce those artefacts appearing on the DC output lines as a common-mode noise.

If you can believe the diagrams, the first device is rated at 60 watts and requires no PFC front-end and, reading between the lines, probably just about gets-away without an output capacitor to earth. The 2nd device is a 75 watt output type (with PFC front-end) and, may need the extra help that the capacitor brings in order to keep output common-mode emissions within the prescribed limits. The second device requires its chassis to be earthed hence it's no problem to solve output noise issues with the capacitor.